# MVC5 T4 ModelMetadata.Properties IsNullable or IsRequired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to create a replacement T4 template for the MVC5 Controller.
I have everything working except for one issue.

I need to generate code for each property in the Model, and looping through `ModelMetadata.Properties` is actually really easy. However it is not an array of `PropertyInfo`s. Rather it is an array of `PropertyMetadata` which doesn't seem to have any information about whether a property is required or not or if its type is nullable or not. So properties in your model of type `int` and `int?` both show up as type `System.Int32`.

Furthermore there is no way to get a list of `PropertyInfo`s being that you can't really get a `Type` Object for the model which you are scaffolding, being that only the short type name is passed to the template.

In summation: Is there any way to know in a T4 template if a property is nullable?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but [ModelMetadata.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) is `IEnumerable<ModelMetadata>` which contains properties including `IsRequired`, `IsNullableValueType` and `ModelType`. Perhaps show some code with what your trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. The `ModelMetadata` provided by scaffolding is `Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata.ModelMetadata` not `System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata`. So the `Properties` property is actually `PropertyMetadata[]` not `IEnumerable<ModelMetadata>`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I don't think so. The project became too much to upkeep. If I ever revisit this it will be under vs2017 which uses Razor instead of T4 and the whole pipeline has been redone

Comment: I also faced the same problem. Even I used `<#= property.DefaultValue #>` on a nullable property such as `int?` it is still 0,

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

What needs to happen is to be able to crosswalk between the two entirely different classes

**From**: [`Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata.PropertyMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.MetaData.PropertyMetaData#Properties)
**To**: [`System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo#Properties)

The `PropertyMetadata` class provided by ASP.NET Scaffolding exposes a relatively limited data, and no direct link to the original type or it's attributes.

> **Here's a comparison of the two properties** :
>   [image: Property Comparison]
>   <sup>(click for full res)</sup>

*because, honestly, why spend all this time working with a custom model generator without having access to the rich world of data provided by System.Reflection*

#### Solution

1. We're going to build a T4 helper method right inside of our normal web assembly.  This is just any `static` method that can be consumed externally. We'll register it later inside of the T4 file so it can actually be used.

   So add a file like this anywhere in your project:

   `UtilityTools.cs`

   ```cs
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
   namespace UtilityTools
   {
       public static class T4Helpers
       {
           public static bool IsRequired(string viewDataTypeName, string propertyName)
           {
               bool isRequired = false;

               Type typeModel = Type.GetType(viewDataTypeName);
               if (typeModel != null)
               {
                   PropertyInfo pi = typeModel.GetProperty(propertyName);
                   Attribute attr = pi.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
                   isRequired = attr != null;
               }

               return isRequired;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now let's register it by adding your assembly to the **`Imports.include.t4**: file:

   ```html
   <#@ assembly name="C:\stash\cshn\App\MyProj\bin\MyProj.dll" #>
   ```

   [image: Imports.include.t4]

   Much in the same way that other assemblies are loaded, this actually gives us access to any static methods inside of whatever assembly we've loaded, minimally providing accessing to `UtilityTools.T4Helpers.IsRequired`
3. Make sure you Rebuild your application (and possibly reload Visual Studio)
4. Now we can make use of that inside any of our T4 templates like this:

   ```html
   <#= UtilityTools.T4Helpers.IsRequired(ViewDataTypeName, property.PropertyName) #>
   ```

   [image: IsRequired Helper usage]

**Further Reading**:

The above solution is heavily adapted from the following articles & questions:

- [MVC 5 T4 Templates and View Model Property Attributes](https://johniekarr.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/mvc-5-t4-templates-and-view-model-property-attributes/)
- [MVC 4 custom data annotations read in T4 scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279416/1366033)
- [Get scaffolder to generate fields in specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40530823/1366033)

> **Tip**: Debugging T4 templates can sometimes be a bear, so I wrote this test template which helps dump out information from the model so you can easily evaluate ASP.NET is using as values to hydrate `PropertyMetadata`
>   **Gist**: https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/fc9ccfbc2af03462d660257103326509

---

> **Note**: `Type.GetType("Namespace.Qualified.TypeName")` [only works when the type is found in either mscorlib.dll or the currently executing assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825156/1366033). If your model is part of a business library, you either have to use a [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.AssemblyQualifiedName) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465096/1366033):
>
> ```
> Type.GetType("Namespace.Qualified.TypeName,DllName")
> ```
>
> or you can search through [all of the currently executing assemblies like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811046/1366033):
>
> ```
> public static Type GetType(string typeName)
> {
>     var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
>     if (type != null) return type;
>     foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
>     {
>         type = a.GetType(typeName);
>         if (type != null)
>             return type;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```
>
> in order for this to work, you'll have to add any business libraries that contain classes to the list of imported assemblies (same as we did earlier in the imports.t4 file):
>
> ```
> <#@ assembly name="C:\stash\cshn\App\MyProj\bin\MyProj.Business.dll" #>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, with:

1. you must import assemblies

- `<#@ assembly name="System.Web.Mvc.dll" #>`
- Current project Dll : `<#@ assembly name="D:\\TestSample\\TestSample\\bin\\TestSample.dll"#>`
- and models namespace in your project: `<#@ import namespace="TestSample.Models" #>`

2. Add this code in the right place

```
<# 
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
    var T = Type.GetType(ViewDataTypeName+", TestSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    var ss = System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null ,T ,property.PropertyName );#>

    <#= ss.IsRequired #>
```

Hope my code will help you

Comment: and this link help you to use ModelMetadata (ss variable to up)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to detect if a type is nullable when creating a custom t4 scaffolding template.

In my Create t4 template I am able to compare the property [TypeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dn632652%28v%3Dvs.118%29), which is a string, to `"System.Nullable<System.Int32>"` 
Or whatever the nullable type is. In my scenario I needed to detect a nullable datetime, so I was looking for the string `"System.Nullable<System.DateTime>"`

For example:

The default t4 scaffolding template has the following loop, which I have modified to detect if I have a nullable DateTime property:

```
string nullableDateTimeType = "System.Nullable<System.DateTime>";

foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
    bool isNullableDateTime = property.TypeName.Equals(nullableDateTimeType);

    if( isNullableDateTime )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Also note: if you want to detect a type that is not nullable, it would just be a comparison to a string "System.DateTime" or "System.Int32"

For more information on creating a customized t4 scaffolding template based on the default t4 templates, see [How to Create Custom Scaffold Templates in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/create-custom-scaffold-templates-asp-net-mvc/)